# PHP codeigniter splitting string to array by regular expression

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have a text file and want to split the text into array using regular expression. But I am new to regex and don't know how to use it.
The text file format is basically like this:

```
0,"20"1,"100000050"25,"100000050"19,""11,"Masuda"12,"Jin"
I want to split them like:
0: 0,"20"
1: 1,"100000050"
2: 25,"100000050"
...
```

Please help! Any answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the preg_split() function. It operates exactly like split(), except that regular expressions are accepted as input parameters for pattern.

Using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` returns the parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern.

```
preg_split(
  '/([\d]+,\"[0-9a-zA-Z]+\")/',
  $str,
  -1,
  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
```

`/([\d]+,\"[0-9a-zA-Z]+\")/` is the regular expression.

```
/ = start or end of pattern string
[ ... ] = grouping of characters
\d - digits
+ = one or more of the preceeding character or group
, = the literal comma character
\" = the literal quote character
[0-9a-zA-Z] = numbers and letters
```

Comment: I dont know why the regex does not work correctly with the following text: 79-1,"Fresh Sea bass (wild) <Suzuki> L". It always misses <Suzuki>.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a weird formatting so I might miss something, but this should work:

```
([0-9]+,\"([0-9a-z ]+)?\")
```

**Details**

```
[0-9]+            match a digit one or more times (this seems to be an ID of sorts)
,                 match a literal comma
\"([0-9a-z ]+)?\" match an alphanumeric character or a space one or more times, optionally (you have an empty string), between quotes
i                 flag to make it case insensitive
```

Pair it with `preg_match_all()` to get all the matches in an array:

```
<?php
$string = '0,"20"1,"100000050"25,"100000050"19,""11,"Masuda"12,"Jin"';
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+,\"([0-9a-z]+)?\")/i", $string, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

The first array will have what you need.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JGPuH)